# Importing specific cells from excel spreadsheet

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have the following spreadsheet, uploaded at: https://files.fm/u/6uhc3qwr

I am trying to import specific cells of a balance sheet, so under the `Assets` section (approx line 19) we have `Total Current Assets` and then I would like to import all of the `Total current Assets` values for that row.

```
31/12/2016              31/12/2015              31/12/2014          31/12/2013          31/12/2012                      31/12/2011          31/12/2010          31/12/2009          31/12/2008          31/12/2007      
th USD              th USD              th USD          th USD          th USD                      th USD          th USD          th USD          th USD          th USD      

    21.855.481              23.407.658          30.740.856              35.002.444          34.819.795                      36.161.838          24.317.544          20.191.164          51.185.242          22.041.144
```

The difficult part for me is to import this data along with the date row a few lines above. I am not trying to import row 19 of the data file but the values corresponding to the row name `Total Current Assets`. I have many of these balance sheets and the excel row number changes slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 library(xlsx)
 library(tidyverse)

 # Read the data from excel file
 df <- read.xlsx('~/Downloads/balance_upload_stack.xlsx',
                 sheetIndex = 1, stringsAsFactors = F)

 # Identify the rows of interest based on the name and subset the original data.frame
 rows_of_interest <- which(df[,1] %in% c("Annual report/Consolidated"," Total Current Assets"))
 new_df <- df[rows_of_interest,]
 new_df <- new_df[!(duplicated(new_df[,1])),]

 # Remove the column with NA and align the data which are spread across different columns
 new_df <- new_df[colSums(!is.na(new_df)) > 0]
 new_df <- cbind(Index = rev(new_df[,1]), 
                 new_col = na.omit(unlist(new_df[,-1]))) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Output dataframe

```
                      Index          new_col
       Total Current Assets 21855481.4195938
 Annual report/Consolidated       31/12/2016
       Total Current Assets    23407658.3146
 Annual report/Consolidated       31/12/2015
       Total Current Assets 30740855.9858115
 Annual report/Consolidated       31/12/2014
       Total Current Assets 35002443.8754019
 Annual report/Consolidated       31/12/2013
       Total Current Assets 34819794.6592976
 Annual report/Consolidated       31/12/2012
       Total Current Assets 36161837.8907298
 Annual report/Consolidated       31/12/2011
       Total Current Assets 24317543.6967938
 Annual report/Consolidated       31/12/2010
       Total Current Assets 20191164.1378803
 Annual report/Consolidated       31/12/2009
       Total Current Assets 51185242.2723579
 Annual report/Consolidated       31/12/2008
       Total Current Assets 22041143.7373581
 Annual report/Consolidated       31/12/2007
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, now the challenge for me is to do this but for all of the rows and years, thanks again though!